# Export custom chart from microstrategy dashboard

Tags: d3.js, charts, microstrategy

I want to export my custom chart as PDF in MicroStrategy. I am using D3.js with MicroStrategy 10.4 to build my own charts but I have a problem with the export.

Is there some code which I probably miss to enable the export function? You can find my JS code at [GitHub](https://github.com/xnappy/d3Charts/blob/master/verticalD3BarChart/javascript/mojo/js/source/verticalD3BarChart.js).

This picture is what I see on MicroStrategy if I am creating a new Dashboard with my personal D3 chart.
[image: What I see]

But what I get after clicking "Export to PDF" I have this result:
[image]

I just see a table. But if I am trying to export one of the standard charts from MicroStrategy it works! So I think the porblem is in my JS code.

Can someone tell me that I am right with my guess or is the export-functionallity just available for the standard charts?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I found a solution but it isn't a good solution. I just click print on my keyboard and I did get my chart as PDF and can use it without loosing quality (not like a Screenshot)

Comment: Hey this is pretty cool. 
There's a bunch of already converted to MSTR format visualizations here: https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Custom-Visualization-Gallery/bg-p/vizgallery
I was going to suggest trying to print from one of those and seeing if it works, and if it does then perhaps there's something in the code. My other thoughts are perhaps SVG vs canvas makes a difference

Comment: Hey I will try it tomorrow and will let you know. I knew this page but I didnt think about it to try the print as pdf with those

Comment: @Davos i installed three of the plugins but the export to pdf didn't work well. I just get a table like with my plugins. But it was a nice idea.

Comment: I've been trying to print from some of the other plugins e.g. Esri connector, and noticed it prints correctly from FireFox but not from Chrome. That's something else to try, but grasping at straws now.

Comment: nope :/ propably MicroStrategy does not allow to export custom charts but dunno why they would do that. I am using SVG so for my goal it was enough to print the page and then work with inkspace or sth like that.